# Remove addons from Aptana Studio 3 (e.g. PyDev)

Tags: aptana, aptana3

Aptana is a very heavy program.

I do not need Ruby/Python, how can I remove these plugins/addons to make it lighter for what I do?

Also how would I delete 'bundles' under the commands submenu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really possible to remove those items in the built application at the moment. There is some discussion about providing a very simple installer with one-click installs of extra languages, but we don't yet have an ETA on that. You can follow this ticket https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-4583 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do it in reverse. If Aptana is built on Eclipse, maybe there's a way to install Eclipse and then selectively install plugins to make it effectively equivalent to Aptana.